# Непонятные ошибки при считывании данных из файла

Tags: c++, база-данных

Здраствуйте, я делаю базу данных в консольном приложении на С++. У меня есть файлы с данными, которые нужно отфильтровать. Проект я делаю с использованием хедеров, где описываю классы и методы классов. В чем же ПРОБЛЕМА. При попытке отфильтровать данные за заданым критерием, компилируя проект, видает 2 какие-то непонятные ошыбки, хотя в самом написанном коде компилятор ошибок не выдает. Я хочу реализовать 4 запрос. Помогите разобратся)
Код файлов .cpp и .h
Main файл

```
#include "Additionals.h"
#include "CompetitionsFunctions.h"
    
    using namespace std;

//class Sport_clubs {
//public:
//    void Show_all_clubs() {};
//     
//};
//
//class Sport_sporudy {
//public: 
//    void Show_sporudy() {};
//
//};
//
//
//class Organisators {
//public:
//    void Show_organisators() {};
//
//};
//
//class Competitions : public Organisators, Sport_sporudy {
//public:
//    void Show_competitions() {};
//
//};
//
//class Coachs : public Sport_clubs {
//public:
//    void Show_coachs() {}
//
//};
//
//class Sportsmen : public Sport_clubs, Coachs {
//public:
//    void Show_sportmen() {};
//    void Show_best_sportmen() {};
//    void Show_free_sportsmen() {};
//    void Show_pryzery() {};
//    void Show_rozryad() {};
//
//};

int state_Menu;
void Menu() {
    cout << "Виберіть дію:" << endl
        << "1. Перелік спортивних клубів міста" << endl
        << "2. Список спортсменів певного клубу, що займаються зазначеним видом спорту" << endl
        << "3. Список тренерів певного клубу за певним видом спорту" << endl
        << "4. Перелік змагань, проведених з певного виду спорту" << endl
        << "5. Список призерів змагань із зазначеного виду спорту" << endl
        << "6. Список найкращих(по кількості зайнятих призових місць) спортсменів міста" << endl
        << "7. Список спортсменів, які не брали участь в жодних змаганнях" << endl
        << "8. Список спортсменів певного розряду зазначеного спортивного клубу" << endl
        << "9. Список організаторів змагань та число проведених ними змагань" << endl
        << "10. Перелік змагань проведених зазначеним організатором" << endl
        << "11. Перелік спортивних клубів і число спортсменів цих клубів, що брали участь у змаганнях" << endl
        << "12. Перелік спортивних споруд міста зазначеного типу в цілому або такі що задовольняють заданим характеристикам" << endl
        << "13. Перелік змагань, які проводились на зазначених спортивних спорудах міста" << endl
        << "0. Вихід з програми" << endl
        << "Ваш вибір: ";
    cin >> state_Menu;

}

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    Menu();

    int _size = 0; 
    Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions = new Competitions_Data[_size];
    DataCompReading(arrCompetitions, _size, "Competitions.txt");

    while (state_Menu != 0)
    {
        switch (state_Menu)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            showOnlySportClubs();
            cout << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 4: //Перелік змагань, проведених з певного виду спорту
            system("cls");
            if (_size != 0) {
                findCompBySport(arrCompetitions, _size);
            }
            else {
                cout << "Файл порожній!" << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 5:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 6:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 7:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 8:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 9:
            system("cls");
            showOrganisators();
            cout << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 10:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 11:
            system("cls");
            showSportClubs();
            cout << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 12:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;
        case 13:
            system("cls");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Пункт введено не вірно" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            Menu();
            break;

        }
    }

    system("cls");
    cout << "Роботу закінчено!" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Competitions.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct Competitions {
    string comp_name, comp_sport, comp_org, comp_sporuda;
};

class Competitions_Data {
protected:
    Competitions comp_data;
public:
    Competitions_Data();
    Competitions_Data(Competitions comp_data_);
    ~Competitions_Data();

    void Print();
    void DataEntry(Competitions comp_data_);

    Competitions GetCompData() { return comp_data; }

    Competitions_Data& operator = (Competitions_Data d_o);
};
```

Competitions.cpp

```
#include "Competitions.h"

Competitions_Data::Competitions_Data() {
    comp_data.comp_name = "";
    comp_data.comp_sport = "";
    comp_data.comp_org = "";
    comp_data.comp_sporuda = "";
    
}
Competitions_Data::Competitions_Data(Competitions comp_data_) {
    comp_data.comp_name = comp_data_.comp_name;
    comp_data.comp_sport = comp_data_.comp_sport;
    comp_data.comp_org = comp_data_.comp_org;
    comp_data.comp_sporuda = comp_data_.comp_sporuda;
}

Competitions_Data::~Competitions_Data() {
}
void Competitions_Data::Print() {
    cout << "Назва змагання: " << comp_data.comp_name << endl;
    cout << "Вид спорту: " << comp_data.comp_sport << endl;
    cout << "Організатор: " << comp_data.comp_org << endl;
    cout << "Спортивна споруда: " << comp_data.comp_sporuda << endl;
}

void Competitions_Data::DataEntry(Competitions comp_data_) {
    comp_data.comp_name = comp_data_.comp_name;
    comp_data.comp_sport = comp_data_.comp_sport;
    comp_data.comp_org = comp_data_.comp_org;
    comp_data.comp_sporuda = comp_data_.comp_sporuda;
}
Competitions_Data& Competitions_Data::operator=(Competitions_Data arrCompetitions_o) {
    this->comp_data.comp_name = arrCompetitions_o.comp_data.comp_name;
    this->comp_data.comp_sport = arrCompetitions_o.comp_data.comp_sport;
    this->comp_data.comp_org = arrCompetitions_o.comp_data.comp_org;
    this->comp_data.comp_sporuda = arrCompetitions_o.comp_data.comp_sporuda;
    
    return *this;
}
```

CompetitionsFunctions.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Competitions.h"

void DataEntry(Competitions_Data* (arrCompetitions), int& mass);
void DataCompReading(Competitions_Data* (&arrCompetitions), int& mass, string fileName);
void showComp(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass);
void Copy(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions_n, Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions_o, int mass);
void findCompBySport(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass);
void DataSave(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass, string fileName);
```

CompetitionsFunctions.cpp

```
    #include "CompetitionsFunctions.h"
        
        void DataEntry(Competitions_Data* (&arrCompetitions), int& mass) {
            Competitions competitions;
            cout << "Введіть розмір масиву: ";
        cin >> mass;
        arrCompetitions = new Competitions_Data[mass];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
            char e; cin.get(e);
            cout << "Введіть назву змагання: ";
            getline(cin, competitions.comp_name, '\n');
            cout << "Введіть вид спорту змагання: ";
            getline(cin, competitions.comp_sport, '\n');
            cout << "Введіть організатора: ";
            cin >> competitions.comp_org;
            cout << "Введіть спортивну споруду: ";
            getline(cin, competitions.comp_sporuda, '\n');
            //add new data to element of array
            arrCompetitions[i].DataEntry(competitions);
            cout << "_______________________\n";
        }
    }
    void DataСompReading(Competitions_Data* (&arrCompetitions), int& mass, string fileName) {
        ifstream fin(fileName);
        if (fin) {
            Competitions competitions;
            fin >> mass;
            arrCompetitions = new Competitions_Data[mass]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
                getline(fin, competitions.comp_name);
                getline(fin, competitions.comp_sport);
                getline(fin, competitions.comp_org);
                getline(fin, competitions.comp_sporuda);
                arrCompetitions[i].DataEntry(competitions);
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Problem with file opening!" << endl;
        }
        fin.close();
    }
    
    void showComp(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
            cout << "Змагання #" << i + 1 << endl;
            arrCompetitions[i].Print();
            cout << "_______________________________________\n";
        }
    }
    void Copy(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions_n, Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions_o, int mass) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
            arrCompetitions_n[i] = arrCompetitions_o[i];
        }
    }
        
    void findCompBySport(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass) {
        string sport;
        cout << "Введіть вид спорту: ";
        cin >> sport;
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
            if (arrCompetitions[i].GetCompData().comp_sport == sport) {
                cout << "Змагання #" << i + 1 << endl;
                arrCompetitions[i].Print();
                    cout << "_______________________\n";
            }
        }
    }
    
    void DataSave(Competitions_Data* arrCompetitions, int mass, string fileName) {
        ofstream fout(fileName);
        if (fout) {
            fout << mass << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < mass; i++) {
                fout << arrCompetitions[i].GetCompData().comp_name << endl
                    << arrCompetitions[i].GetCompData().comp_sport << endl
                    << arrCompetitions[i].GetCompData().comp_org << endl
                    << arrCompetitions[i].GetCompData().comp_sporuda << endl;
                if (i < mass - 1) {
                    fout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Проблеми з відкриттям файлу!";
        }
        cout << "Дані про змагання збережено: " << endl;
        fout.close();
    }
```

Код ошыбки

```
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl DataCompReading(class Competitions_Data * &,int &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?DataCompReading@@YAXAEAPEAVCompetitions_Data@@AEAHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) в функции main.  Kursova robota  D:\KURSOVA\Kursova robota\Kursova robota.obj    1   


Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1  Kursova robota  D:\KURSOVA\Kursova robota\x64\Debug\Kursova robota.exe  1
```

Comment: Где тело функции `DataCompReading`? На будущее, показывайте ошибки текстом, а не картинками - и не эту таблицу, а вкладку output.

Comment: тело функции в CompetitionsFunctions.cpp

Comment: В CompetitionsFunctions.cpp в имени функции опечатка - там кажется кириллическая `C`

Comment: да, дело было в этом, спасибо